# Couchdb....HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, couchdb

I am having trouble with getting an HTTP PUT method working with a Couchdb create database. Nothing scary about the code, you have all seen it before so won't post it, as its too boring. Error message when using a put Method is Connection is Closed. Is there something I should be aware of....something really noddy. I am getting a 404 when I use a POST method which is correct in the context of creating a new DB with Couchdb. Any help much appreciated. Can HTTPWebRequest do a PUT method?, if it can not then I am baffled to why not.

more specific : the error is : The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

I have checked Couchdb with CURL...and it works just fine.

error comes at this point...after setting the method to "PUT"

```
Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
```

code snippet:

```
private string DataViaHTTP(string url, Dictionary<string, string> parameters, string content, string contentType, int timeout, bool contentIsParam, string method)
{
    byte[] requestData;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest;

        if (contentIsParam == false)
        {
            requestData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
            httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BuildParamString(url, parameters));
        }
        else
        {
            requestData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(BuildParamString(null, parameters));
            httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        }

        httpWebRequest.Method = method;
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = contentType;

        if (timeout > 0)
        {
            httpWebRequest.Timeout = timeout;
        }

        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
        Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        // Read and return the response stream
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream outStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();


        var stringStream = String.Empty;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(outStream))
        {
            stringStream = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        }

        return stringStream;
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        throw e;
    }
}
```

this didn't work either :(

```
public string PutCommand(string url)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
        {
            webclient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.249.89 Safari/532.5";
            webclient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
            var x = webclient.UploadData(url, "PUT", new byte[] {});
            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(x);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though the code is boring, the error must be in there.

Comment: Its the same code I have used for years with both GET AND POST.

Comment: Really, honestly, if you want help on it you should show us the exact code you're using.  No offense.

Comment: knock yourself out @ross

Answer (score 1):

I know that this isn't a solution to the problem, but is there some reason why you can't use the [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class if you just want to grab data from a URL? It would eliminate a lot of the cluttered code you wrote. You can literally use it with one line, like this:

```
string data = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"http://whateverURL.com/?options=1&somethingElse=5");
```

Comment: Only used it in earnest with simple data, can it do POST and PUT commands or is it just GET?

Comment: Read the MSDN page I linked to... the `UploadString()` method can perform HTTP POSTs.

Comment: just did, thanks @SpikeX. Will check it out. If it solves the current dilemma will ditch the old code and plug in the webClient stuff.

Comment: If you're still having the error: *"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."*, this means that the server is most likely terminating the connection in an unexpected way (probably earlier than what the client expected it to be). This is either a problem with the server itself, or a problem with how you are requesting data from the server. Your problem is **not**, however, with the type of connection you're creating (either with `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient`).

Comment: Well, done the same thing with python, and CURL and there seems to be libraries out there for c# and Couchdb...so must be able to be done....but how?